# SQL Constraint Verification Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint, check-constraints

I want to check during a request if the constraint are respected, if they are not instead of sending an ERROR message, simply return FALSE. How would I do that?

Example of TABLE I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
    name   VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    leaf   INT CHECK (leaf > 0)
);
```

Example of Functions I'd use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_tree(name, nb_leaf) RETURNS BOOLEAN;
CREATE FUNCTION remove_leaf(tree_name, leaf_to_remove) RETURNS BOOLEAN;
```

In my function it would be too repetitive to check for the name

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tree WHERE name=tree_name) THEN...
```

Since I already have a UNIQUE constraint, but if I don't check I get the error message of course, how do I not use the check (IF..) and not get the error message but a return false instead when the input is wrong?

PS: I'm using postgresql if that changes anything

Comment: In Oracle you are able to create user defined exceptions. I am pretty sure this must be possible in postgress also. When the error is executed you can return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exception is raised, return false from your function:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   return false;
END;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

At the end of the page you will see an example:

```
DECLARE
  text_var1 text;
  text_var2 text;
  text_var3 text;
BEGIN
  -- some processing which might cause an exception
  ...
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS text_var1 = MESSAGE_TEXT,
                          text_var2 = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
                          text_var3 = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;
END;
```

Comment: but this syntax will force me the do
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tree WHERE name=tree_name) THEN ... which doesnt differ from doing it in my core function no? (because i cant use WHEN raise exception I get an error at "raise")

Comment: In your function add_tree you can write an insert (i guess you do) and when this failes because of unique constraint or other error your EXCEPTION will catch it and return false. In Oracle you can use EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN. In postgresql also.

Comment: @sourpet you are welcome. Would you pls vote up for me?

Comment: Need more reputation to upvote but you're the accepted answer can't do more :p